# Какие факторы определяют модель вычислений языка программирования?

Tags: любой-язык

> Каждый язык имеет свою **модель вычислений.** Действия, предписываемые языком совершенно по-разному могут достигать одни и те же цели. ([источник](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/40/40/lecture/1182?page=2))

Какие существенные факторы определяют и соответственно, выделяют модель вычислений языка программирования?

Comment: Про это же следующая лекция Модели вычислений: http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/40/40/lecture/1184

Comment: Я считаю этот вопрос интересным, потому вынес его сюда. Так же интересно мнение участников ruSO. Ответ здесь может ведь не совпадать с ответом в указанном источнике.

Comment: Плюс может кто-то возмется своеобразно сформулировать ответ развернутый в источнике.